# Gregorian calendar Day_Of_Week returns wrong day

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Calendar Setting Incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598036/java-calendar-setting-incorrectly)

i have this code:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.set(Integer.parseInt(Year), Integer.parseInt(Month), Integer.parseInt(Day));
int weekday= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

If i pass for example 2012-04-02 (a Monday) weekday = 4. And if i pass 2012-04-06(a Friday) weekday = 1. So gregorianCalendar thinks friday is the first day altough I said Monday is the first day? How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(Month)` you know that January is 0, right?

Comment: hahaha oooh noo, i forgot that
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 in `GregorianCalendar` is May, not April, so the answer is correct. When you insert 4 as `Calendar.MONTH`, the date is actually 02/05/2012, which is a Wednesday.

Remember that months are 0-based.